# How can I create an ActivityScenario that starts in INITIALIZED or CREATED state?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-testing

Google talks in their documentation of how you can manually transition the states of an Activity under test using ActivityScenarios and their function `moveToState`. But whatever I do, my Activities are already in RESUMED state when I get to the point where my unit test code starts executing. No matter if I use `ActivityScenario` directly, `ActivityScenarioRule` or the new kotlin extension `launchActivity`

I'm running the test as a unit test using `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)` in the `/test` folder, not `/androidTest`

Unlike their counterpart `launchFragment`, `launchActivity` does not have a parameter `initialState` which I can set.

What's the point of `moveToState` if the only state I can move to is DESTROYED? I need to hook up stuff after `onCreate` but before `onStart`!

Ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/testing

Comment: "What's the point of moveToState if the only state I can move to is DESTROYED?" - that's not the only state you can move to, as shown in the very docs you linked to. "I need to hook up stuff after onCreate but before onStart!" What do you need to "hook up" in that time for the sake of a test? Can you start the test, move to `CREATED`, "hook up" whatever you need, move to `STARTED`, then verify?

Comment: "that's not the only state you can move to, as shown in the very docs you linked to" - Well the docs are wrong. You can't move to state CRATED without also simultaneously moving to STARTED. I need to hook up dependency injection with the activity instance as key before "onCreate" using Toothpick DI

Comment: "Well the docs are wrong. You can't move to state CRATED without also simultaneously moving to STARTED" - please indicate where the docs say you can move to `CREATED` without moving to `STARTED`. Just because the API doesn't work the way you'd like, doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: We're splitting hairs here - the point is I can't execute code between `CREATED` and `STARTED` state no matter what the doc says. The answer to your second question in the comment from Apr 23 is "no".

Comment: Maybe you can pass some parameters in the intent you launch the activity with?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to hook up stuff after `onCreate` but before `onStart`!

If this is what you want exactly, try using Hilt to do dependencies injection,
and replace the instance binding in unit test with `@TestInstallIn`, and do whatever you want with the stub instance before `ActivityScenario.launch(Activity)`.

Note: you still cannot access to the activity instance in `CREATED` state this moment.

See: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#replace-binding

---

I was struggling with repalce the datasource in unit test before using Hilt too, hoping this could help a little.

Comment: I appreciate suggestion using Hilt. However we are already committed to a different DI framework - Toothpick. In fact, the inner workings of Toothpick is the very reason I need to get ahold of the activity instance before "onCreate" since I need that to set up mocks before onCreate.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Toothpick, but I found an example about doing injection in unit test case here https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick/blob/master/toothpick-sample/src/test/java/com/example/toothpick/activity/SimpleBackpackItemsActivityTest.kt . Maybe you should take a look at it, or provide an example project for open-debugging 

Comment: The example you link to doesn't go into detail about replacing runtime bindings with unit test bindings for an activity scope. However we're weering off topic here - probably a case of the XY Problem. I do think that the original question as phrased deserves a proper answer regardless of possibilities in the Toothpick framework. Maybe the answer is "It's not possible' - I'd be content with that. I will consider asking a separate question about Toothpick injection and provide an example project there.